# Java Play Framework 2.0 using Hibernate in test framework

Tags: java, hibernate, playframework-2.0

I'm wondering if anyone has got automated tests working with Play 2.0 using Hibernate as the persistance engine?

I'm attempting the following test but I get this errror:

```
[error] Test tests.TestApp.findById failed: No EntityManager bound to this threa
d. Try to annotate your action method with @play.db.jpa.Transactional
[error]     at play.db.jpa.JPA.em(JPA.java:45)
[error]     at models.User.findById(User.java:72)
[error]     at tests.TestApp$1.run(TestApp.java:55)
[error]     at play.test.Helpers.running(Helpers.java:277)
[error]     at tests.TestApp.findById(TestApp.java:51)
```

The test code is:

```
@Test
public void findById() 
{
    running(fakeApplication(), new Runnable() 
    {
       public void run() 
       {
           User user = User.findById(21l);
           assertThat(user.getName()).isEqualTo("Dave");
       }
    });
}
```

I tried adding the @Transactional anotation to the test method but this has no effect.

Then I tried adding setup and teardown methods that bind to the current JPA thread but had no luck with this either. Although I am not sure if I am doing it correctly.

```
private EntityManager em;


@Transactional
@Before
public void setUp() 
{
    em = JPA.em("org.hibernate.ejb.HibernatePersistence");
    JPA.bindForCurrentThread(em);
}

@After
public void tearDown() 
{
    JPA.bindForCurrentThread(null);
    em.close();
}
```

This gives the following error:

```
[error] Test tests.TestApp.findById failed: There is no started application
[error]     at scala.sys.package$.error(package.scala:27)
[error]     at play.api.Play$$anonfun$current$1.apply(Play.scala:44)
[error]     at play.api.Play$$anonfun$current$1.apply(Play.scala:44)
[error]     at scala.Option.getOrElse(Option.scala:108)
[error]     at play.api.Play$.current(Play.scala:44)
[error]     at play.api.Play.current(Play.scala)
[error]     at play.Play.application(Play.java:12)
[error]     at play.db.jpa.JPA.em(JPA.java:21)
[error]     at tests.TestApp.setUp(TestApp.java:26)
[error]     ...
```

If anybody can provide any assistance I will appreciate it greatly!

Answer (score 0):

Try this pattern:

```
running(fakeApplication(), new Runnable()
{
  public void run()
  {
    JPA.withTransaction(new play.libs.F.Callback0()
    {
      public void invoke() throws DataAccessException
      {
        ...
      }
    });
  }
});
```

[Here](https://groups.google.com/forum/#!topic/play-framework/kVL9G-CkT1M)'s another example which shows the logic in setup and teardown methods as you have tried with bindForCurrentThread, in an abstract base class.